# What is the best way to catch an IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, exception

When would be the best use of this type of exception and is it handeled properly if caught in a catch like so?

```
catch(Exception e)
```

Or does it need to be caught explicitly?

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It *would* be caught by the first - but so would a bunch of other exceptions. You shouldn't catch more than you really want to.

The second is better if you really *have* to catch it... but *usually* this indicates a bug in the calling code. Sometimes this is a case of another method higher up not validating *its* arguments, etc. In an ideal world, any time that `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown there should be a way for the caller to validate the value before passing it in, or call a version which will fail in a non-exceptional way (e.g. the `TryParse` pattern in .NET, which is admittedly harder in Java without `out` parameters). That's not always the case, but whenever you get an `IllegalArgumentException` it's worth checking to see whether you *could* avoid it by checking the values before calling the method.

Answer (score 9):

You should not handle an IllegalArgumentException. It's porpose is to inform the developer, that he have called a method with wrong arguments. Solution is, to call the method with other arguments.

If you must catch it you should use

```
catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
```

Comment: Unless the library which throws it needs to reexamine the exception at a higher level before it exits upward to the caller.

Answer (score 5):

You should stay away from `catch (Exception)` since that way you'll catch *every* possible exception. If you really only *expect* the `IllegalArgumentException` and handle that case you shouldn't broaden that scope; better add more catch blocks for other types of exceptions, then.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the case at hand, either is correct in itself. Without narrowing down the scope of the question, it's a bit hard to give a "best use" example.