# Java catching image not found exception

Tags: java, exception, illegalargumentexception

```
    try{
       IMAGE = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("Images/image.png"));
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Error<br>Missing images</html>" ,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

The catch block is not working, I still get the default message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at KPK.<init>(KPK.java:40)
at Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

How can I catch this exceptiont?

Comment: Just add another catch block for that exception.

Comment: @OldProgrammer: no, that's not a good idea.

Comment: Why is everyone suggesting that he should catch IllegalArgumentException? This exception should **not** be caught, and doing so suggests that something is very wrong with the program. Please folks, let's give newbies *good* advice. Again, please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117541/what-is-the-best-way-to-catch-an-illegalargumentexception) for more on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First and foremost, **DON'T** catch the `IllegalArgumentException`. This error suggests something very bad in your code, and shouldn't really be caught. See Jon Skeet's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2117556/522444) for more on why this is bad. Instead you should:
2. Separate the code in your line where you read your image.
3. First get the URL from the `getResource()`
4. Check if it's null
5. If null don't call `ImageIO.read(...)` with it.
6. You should learn and follow Java naming conventions so that others will better understand your code. For instance, don't capitalize non-constant variables.

i.e.,

```
try{
  URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH); // path should be a constant 
                                          // or variable, not a String literal
  if (imgUrl == null) {
    // show error and get the heck out of here
  } else {
    image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
  }
} catch (IOException ex){
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "<html>Error<br>Missing images</html>" ,
       "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException ex)`

Also, create an image first...`Image im = null;` then use the file... `im = ImageIO.read(new File("YOUR IMAGE FILE PATH"));`

Comment: It's "seems" to be an embedded resource, not a `File` ;)

Comment: See comment to original question. -1

Comment: Yes, I agree it's not a good idea....but if he REALLY wants to use the catch block, then why stop him?

Comment: because he is wrong and didn't know any better, and our job is to show him a better way. If you're going to post your solution, you should at least explain why it's bad. But having said that, as @mad already suggests, your solution is wrong since it uses files not URL's.

Comment: Generally speaking, a bad practice is a bad practice and we see more of that each day. If you were teaching them to shoot, would you let them shoot themselves in the foot?  Why should it be any different here.  Yes, if they choose to ignore use, then that's they're problem, at least we made the effort...IMHO